# Authenticating Devices - Unsupported type

Tags: facebook, authentication, device

I want to use the device authentication as described in the documentation ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/ ) but I can't use it to authenticate with my facebook app, the return is always:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported type: 'device_code'. Supported types: web_server, user_agent, client_cred, username",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

This seems to a be a known problem for several months. I've found several people with the same problem but it seems that they gave up or didn't bother to post the solution (example: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=91645#p322091 )

Can anyone use "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/device?type=device_code&client_id=150792241632891" with their own applicationID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another answer here but it seems that device auth for Facebook is behind a whitelist, i'm not sure how to apply - the docs probably shouldn't be publicly visible if the functionality isn't though, i'll try to see why that is

Comment: Thanks. I tried the other solution and it wasn't that.

If you find a solution or an alternative please post it.

Comment: I checked it out with the team working on it, it's pretty much still in the beta/testing phase and hasn't been finalised or released, the docs not making it clear that this is the case in an error, I'll update them tomorrow